# Rolling Effect - Cocos2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

How would I go about making a sprite "Roll Up" like the app "[Roll It Up](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/roll-it-up/id399010506?mt=8)" on the App Store?

Does anyone know? Can anyone lead me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See this Mac Apple app. Here they used CoreImage. This might helps you.
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/CITransitionSelectorSample/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: I'm really looking for something that you use touch with.  E.g. You move your finger up and the sprite starts to "roll" up. But the sprite needs to "roll" up as fast or as slow as your finger is moving

Answer (score 0):

This is incredibly basic.  My "jerk" answer is this:  Do some tutorials and learn how to use cocos2d.

My non "jerk" answer is this:  You need to use CCTouchesBegan to find what is being touched, CCTouchesMoved to move the sprite (hint:  touch position = sprite position), and CCAction methods for animating the sprite.

The best advice I can give is to go to this site  [RayWenderlich.com (iOS development tutorials)](http://www.raywenderlich.com/)

Comment: Well man I won't be a jerk because for one, I already knew that and second, ccaction cannot tell the velocity of the swipe. The sprite needs to roll up as fast as the user moves their finger or as slow. One more thing I already did read through those tutorials...

Comment: Moving a sprite is as simple as setting it's position.  If you are using Box2D bodies then it is a little different, but basic Cocos2D is designed to make things as easy as possible.  You can either set the position of the sprite to the position of the touch, or you can do something like CCMoveTo combined with [self scheduleUpdate] (or whatever).